# Extracting PowerQuery results when one of the steps crashed

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

Does anyone have a way to extract power query results when one of the steps crashed (and lets say there is no way to fix it)? There are a lot of working pivot tables based on power queries so there has to be data somewhere. There is also a Data Model in power pivot and I know that I can copy all the results from power pivot and paste into some worksheet but it crashes power pivot when I want to copy so many results

Comment: (a) why cant you fix it ? (b) If the powerquery is somehow dead but the pivot tables based on the powerquery are there, you should be able to double click the total rows to extract the source data behind the pivot reports, at least so far as the data originally passed from the powerquery

Comment: (a) I cant fix it because i dont have access to the source and this that's the step that crashed 
(b) doesnt it return only first 1000 rows?

Comment: Well, try it and see

Answer (score 0):

I depends whether or not it as ever worked.

To my knowledge, `PowerQuery` only has a preview of the data. So, it does not retain a copy of the source. Even though I don't know if you can access these previews in a meaningful way.

However, if it as loaded in `PowerBI` at some point (when you hit "Apply" in `PowerQuery`). You can extract it in its current state using [DAX Studio](https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/dax-studio/). You'll get more or less exactly what you can see in `PowerBI` except there is an option to extract to CSV.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into Existing Connections and check Table that corresponds to power query and then you can load it to a sheet even if the power query is down